# Show that $s\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2(s^2+t^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ where $u=f(x,y) ; x=s^2-t^2,y=2st$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I want to obtain the result

$$s\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2(s^2+t^2)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

where,
$$u=f(x,y) \text{ and } x=s^2-t^2,y=2st$$

So far I obatined,
$$s\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}-t\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=2(s^2+t^2)$$

To get this I used,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$
and
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$

I don't know how to obtained the desired results.
Am I doing something wrong?
If so what is te correct way of doing this?

Comment: $$u = f(x,y) = f(x(s,t),y(s,t)) \implies \frac{\partial u}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct derivatives should be,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$

and,
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$